# 5.3 kernel crash on s2idle suspend

Tags: kernel, amd-graphics, amd-ryzen

I'm trying to get s2idle suspend working on an HP Envy x360 laptop with a Ryzen 7 3700U CPU and an AMD/ATI Picasso GPU.  I'm using the 5.3.0-23-generic kernel from Ubuntu 19.10.

I get the following crash:

```
Nov 19 20:58:33 frog kernel: [   95.784642] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Nov 19 20:58:33 frog systemd-sleep[4383]: Suspending system...
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [   95.811609] Filesystems sync: 0.026 seconds
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [   95.812140] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.003 seconds) done.
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [   95.815748] OOM killer disabled.
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [   95.815749] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [   95.817555] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [   95.818087] wlo1: deauthenticating from 04:95:e6:ba:29:0d by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [   95.819236] rtw_pci 0000:02:00.0: sta 04:95:e6:ba:29:0d with macid 0 left
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [   95.819853] rtw_pci 0000:02:00.0: stop vif c0:b5:d7:8b:15:83 on port 0
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [   96.387086] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helper [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring kiq_2.1.0 test failed (-110)
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [   96.387163] [drm:gfx_v9_0_hw_fini [amdgpu]] *ERROR* KCQ disable failed
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.144071] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.3: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.144608] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.4: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184461] WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 4383 at kernel/irq/chip.c:210 irq_startup+0xf3/0x100
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184463] Modules linked in: pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) ccm rfcomm aufs iptable_mangle xt_CHECKSUM xt_tcpudp iptable_nat xt_comment xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bridge stp llc iptable_filter bpfilter binder_linux overlay ashmem_linux(CE) cmac bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel joydev snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm btusb btrtl snd_seq_midi btbcm snd_seq_midi_event btintel rtwpci snd_rawmidi bluetooth edac_mce_amd rtw88 uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops kvm_amd videobuf2_v4l2 ccp videobuf2_common snd_seq ecdh_generic videodev kvm snd_seq_device ecc mc irqbypass mac80211 snd_timer input_leds hp_wmi sparse_keymap wmi_bmof serio_raw cfg80211 snd hid_multitouch snd_pci_acp3x ucsi_acpi k10temp typec_ucsi libarc4 soundcore typec hp_accel mac_hid lis3lv02d input_polldev hp_wireless acpi_tad sch_fq_codel
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184532]  parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 dm_crypt crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel amdgpu hid_generic aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper amd_iommu_v2 gpu_sched i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt nvme fb_sys_fops i2c_piix4 drm nvme_core wmi video i2c_hid hid
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184563] CPU: 6 PID: 4383 Comm: systemd-sleep Tainted: G         C OE     5.3.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184565] Hardware name: HP HP ENVY x360 Convertible 15-ds0xxx/85DD, BIOS F.16 09/12/2019
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184568] RIP: 0010:irq_startup+0xf3/0x100
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184571] Code: e8 02 41 00 00 85 c0 0f 85 fb 09 00 00 4c 89 ef 31 d2 4c 89 f6 e8 5d cc ff ff 4c 89 e7 e8 a5 fe ff ff 41 89 c5 e9 49 ff ff ff <0f> 0b eb ae 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184573] RSP: 0018:ffffa797c3923c98 EFLAGS: 00010002
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184575] RAX: 0000000000000010 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 0000000000000040
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184577] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffffffbe048c00 RDI: ffff98af0e3e9628
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184578] RBP: ffffa797c3923cb8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffff98af0e8003e8
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184579] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffffffffbde67168 R12: ffff98aefea04400
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184581] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: ffff98af0e3e9628 R15: ffff98aefea044a4
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184583] FS:  00007f92604f8940(0000) GS:ffff98af10b80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184584] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184586] CR2: 00007f92610ec998 CR3: 000000038c668000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184587] Call Trace:
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184597]  __enable_irq+0x52/0x60
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184601]  resume_irqs+0xbd/0xf0
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184604]  resume_device_irqs+0x10/0x20
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184610]  dpm_noirq_end+0xe/0x20
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184614]  suspend_enter+0x34e/0x550
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184618]  suspend_devices_and_enter+0x12b/0x260
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184621]  pm_suspend.cold+0x318/0x36b
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184624]  state_store+0x82/0xe0
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184629]  kobj_attr_store+0x12/0x20
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184634]  sysfs_kf_write+0x3e/0x50
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184637]  kernfs_fop_write+0x11e/0x1a0
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184642]  __vfs_write+0x1b/0x40
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184644]  vfs_write+0xb9/0x1a0
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184648]  ksys_write+0x67/0xe0
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184651]  __x64_sys_write+0x1a/0x20
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184656]  do_syscall_64+0x5a/0x130
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184660]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184663] RIP: 0033:0x7f9261333317
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184667] Code: 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb bb 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 10 b8 01 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 51 c3 48 83 ec 28 48 89 54 24 18 48 89 74 24
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184668] RSP: 002b:00007ffdd74c3fb8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184671] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000004 RCX: 00007f9261333317
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184672] RDX: 0000000000000004 RSI: 00007ffdd74c4070 RDI: 0000000000000004
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184673] RBP: 00007ffdd74c4070 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 000055b5addd9e20
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184674] R10: 000055b5addd7010 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000004
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184675] R13: 000055b5addd72d0 R14: 0000000000000004 R15: 00007f926140d8a0
Nov 19 20:58:48 frog kernel: [  110.184678] ---[ end trace ba0bd68e332c6257 ]---
```

Is this a known issue?  What is the right place to raise it as a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got the same problem here, when my computer goes back from suspend, when I get something other than a cursor, it's very laggy and it quickly ends to respond.
Isn't that the same kind of problem ? https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/open-source-amd-linux/1089720-amdgpu-laptop-suspend-hang
It seems that a fix is on its way https://cgit.freedesktop.org/drm/drm/commit/?h=drm-fixes&id=72cda9bb5e219aea0f2f62f56ae05198c59022a7
Strange thing for me is that I'm using a Ryzen 7 3700, like you, but a NVIDIA graphics card...